# Understanding Samba VFS Operations for Full Audit

Tags: freebsd, syslog, truenas, samba4, smb-conf

We have a TrueNAS System running TrueNAS-12.0-U8 for which we are required to **log all successful and all failed file access attempts** for a specific SMB share. The Samba version is 4.13.

Per guidance from the vendor, I've included the below in the auxiliary parameters for the share with the logging requirements. This appears to satisfy my requirement based on my testing.

```
vfs objects = full_audit streams_xattr aio_fbsd ixnas
full_audit:prefix = %u|%I|%S
full_audit:priority = notice
full_audit:success = openat
full_audit:failure = openat
```

I am interested in better understanding all of the VFS operations but have been unable to find a resource that includes definitions. Most of the operations I can find in documentation such as the [Arch Linux VFS Full Audit](https://man.archlinux.org/man/vfs_full_audit.8.en#:%7E:text=vfs_full_audit%20-%20record%20Samba%20VFS%20operations%20in%20the,operations%20to%20the%20system%20log%20using%20syslog%20%283%29.) are self explanatory but others are not.

Can anyone suggest a resource that includes definitions of the VFS operations?

Answer (score 0):

The main ones we use are:
openat - although can be quite chatty
mkdirat
renameat
unlinkat

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/vfs_full_audit.8.html